# Swagger in a React/asp.net project only works in IIS Express

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, swagger

When I launch my project using IIS Express, the GET methods in Swagger function properly. However, when I start the project from `{Projectname}`, I'm encountering a `404` error with this response body. I'm trying to configure Swagger to function correctly within my project.

Any insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

[print screen of the response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiRNm.png)

Comment: so it works when you do it via swagger, but when you make call from react front end it doesnt work?